# Decorate a subset of a generic registration

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I'm using SimpleInjector for my DI container. I have an open generic interface with 2 type arguments

```
public interface IAdapter<TRepository, TEntity>
    where TRepository : AbstractRepository
    where TEntity : AbstractModel, new()
{
}
```

which I register with the container as:

```
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(IAdapter<,>), 
    typeof(Adapter<,>));
```

I would like to decorate IAdapter dependent on the types provided. e.g. (I know this code is not valid but it demonstrates what I'm trying to do)

```
class RepositoryX : AbstractRepository { }
class RepositoryY : AbstractRepository { }
class RepositoryZ : AbstractRepository { }

container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IAdapter<RepositoryY,>), 
    typeof(SpecificAdapterDecorator<,>));

container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IAdapter<[RepositoryX|RepositoryZ],>), 
    typeof(GeneralAdapterDecorator<,>));
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [generic decorator documentation](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Advanced-scenarios#Generic_Decorators):

> There's an overload of the `RegisterDecorator` available that allows you
>   to supply a predicate to determine whether that decorator should be
>   applied to a specific service type. Using a given context you can
>   determine whether the decorator should be applied.

So you will need something like this:

```
container.RegisterDecorator(
    typeof(IAdapter<,>), 
    typeof(SpecificAdapterDecorator<,>), 
    c => c.ServiceType.GetGenericArguments()[0] == typeof(RepositoryY));

container.RegisterDecorator(
    typeof(IAdapter<,>), 
    typeof(GeneralAdapterDecorator<,>), 
    c => c.ServiceType.GetGenericArguments()[0] != typeof(RepositoryY));
```